# Socket.io error in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, ubuntu-12.04

I've just installed node.js, npm and mongodb to a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 server. When I try to open my site I'm getting this error :

```
/home/proj/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:402
        return doneCallback(null, Buffer.concat([sizeBuffer, stringToBuffer(pa
                                         ^
TypeError: Object function Buffer(subject, encoding, offset) {
  if (!(this instanceof Buffer)) {
    return new Buffer(subject, encoding, offset);
  }

  var type;

  // Are we slicing?
  if (typeof offset === 'number') {
    this.length = coerce(encoding);
    this.parent = subject;
    this.offset = offset;
  } else {
    // Find the length
    switch (type = typeof subject) {
      case 'number':
        this.length = coerce(subject);
        break;

      case 'string':
        this.length = Buffer.byteLength(subject, encoding);
        break;

      case 'object': // Assume object is an array
        this.length = coerce(subject.length);
        break;

      default:
        throw new Error('First argument needs to be a number, ' +
                        'array or string.');
    }

    if (this.length > Buffer.poolSize) {
      // Big buffer, just alloc one.
      this.parent = new SlowBuffer(this.length);
      this.offset = 0;

    } else {
      // Small buffer.
      if (!pool || pool.length - pool.used < this.length) allocPool();
      this.parent = pool;
      this.offset = pool.used;
      pool.used += this.length;
    }

    // Treat array-ish objects as a byte array.
    if (isArrayIsh(subject)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        this.parent[i + this.offset] = subject[i];
      }
    } else if (type == 'string') {
      // We are a string
      this.length = this.write(subject, 0, encoding);
    }
  }

  SlowBuffer.makeFastBuffer(this.parent, this, this.offset, this.length);
} has no method 'concat'
    at /home/proj/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:402:42
```

What can be cause to this? Everything is working fine in localhost.

Answer (score 5):

Buffer.concat is only supported in Node 0.8. You will need to upgrade your Node to the latest version. Ubuntu 12.04 only provide Node 0.6

To upgrade, you can run following command

```
$ npm install -g n
$ n stable
```

This will install latest node to /usr/local/bin.

You can run your node app by using

```
$ /usr/local/bin/node path-to-your-node-app
```

Read more about node binary management at https://github.com/tj/n, it helps you manage multiple node binary installation.